# PHP redirect with Range (byte-serving) passthrough

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

I have some PHP code which frequently serves page redirects to clients via the header`('Location: x') function`.  The header redirect works fine; I have no output before the Header function, and the user is successfully redirected to the new page.  Some of the clients that connect have `HTTP byte range requests` tied to them, with the intent to only grab a certain portion of the requesting file that I redirect to.
I need to preserve this range request when sending to the new site; the site I redirect to should also see the range info in their headers, and be able to correctly process the user's request.

I understand that I can see the byte range that they're requesting in my PHP code by looking at `$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']`, but I'm unable to think of a way to pass this range to the redirecting site in their headers.  I'm pretty sure trying to implement via the header function is wrong, since it will set the headers of my own page.  Instead, I need to be able to set the headers that are sent to the page that I'm redirecting to.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't actually need to redirect the user to another site, but just need to give them content from another site, you might want to use cURL functions to where you can set the Content-Range header on the request, get the result, and then serve it up to the end user.

Comment: Mike, that was my first reaction too, but I'm redirecting to audio files (mp3, m4a, etc).  If I were to go this route, it would kill my bandwidth.

Comment: I think your best solution then would be to look solve this at the webserver level since, in essence, it sounds like you need to run your web server as a reverse proxy. If you are running on Apache, you should investigate the mod_proxy and related modules (including mod_headers).